# How to get a single number out of a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

Let's say I have the following `tuple (7,0)`,
how would i get only 7 and set it as the x variable, and only 0 and set it as the y variable.

I have tried

```
   x = int(item[0])

   y = int(item[1])
```

where `item` is a tuple of two numbers that can be (3,2), (5,7), etc.

This throws me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'item' object is not subscriptable
```

I need to be able to compare x and y, which why I need their respective integer.

```
def item_location_game(self, item):
```

item is a class
where

```
Class Item:

    def __init__(self, line, colom):
        self.line = int(line)
        self.colom = int(colom)
```

Comment: (1,2)[1] works fine.  show the rest of your code (for creating item)

Comment: `item`, apparently, is *not a tuple*. Which is what the error is telling you, it is an `item` object

Comment: Your code will work **if** your tuple is called **item**.

Comment: I added a bit more of the code

Comment: What is the output of `print(type(item))` and `print(repr(item))` ?

Comment: not enough context.  where is item being created?  most likely item is a class.  something like `class item: ...`  and you are doing item1=item()  and then item1[0]

Comment: Thanks, I have realise item is a class where

Class Item:

    def __init__(self, line, colom):
        self.line = int(line)
        self.colom = int(colom)

Comment: Look at the edit of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After aclaring that `item` wasn't a tuple, you could try:

```
x=item.line
y=item.colom
```

Comment: Thanks, it tells me TypeError: 'Position' object is not iterable

Comment: @code_legend It means your `item` is not a `tuple`.

Comment: Please give more context... As @GinoMempin, what do you get when you print `item`, or when you do `print(type(item))`?

Comment: it's still the wrong error.  he's giving us the wrong code.  That would throw 'Position' not subscriptable

Comment: Thanks, I have realise item is a class where Class Item: def __init__(self, line, colom): self.line = int(line) self.colom = int(colom) 
        self.colom = int(colom)

Comment: In that case if your'e trying to get `item.line` and `item.colom` atributtes, as `x`, `y`, you could try the las edit.

Answer (score -1):

A tuple in Python can be unpacked. If the tuple will always have two items. Then you can unpack like the following:

```py
x,y = item
print(x)
```

If tuple contain three variables. You can unpack the tuple with the following

```py
x,y,z = item
print(x)
```